# How to turn the service on or off for all users or for users in specific organizational units using API

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-for-education

I have set up a client side application which uses admin sdk to manage google apps cloud.
Is it possible to  turn the service/applications on or off for all users or for users in specific organizational units through APIs

Answer (score 1):

The API does not give you access to enable/disable specific services for Org Units. You need to setup the OUs for the desired levels of access to services and then move users between OUs via the API to control their access to services.

The only other option you have is to use the `blockInheritance` attribute. Enabling/disabling ineritance allows you to control which services are on for an OU at any given time.